# Nginx Serving Images Very Slowly

Tags: windows-server-2008, nginx

I've had some complaints that my [site](http://cranktrain.com) takes a long time to load images in particular, just loading that main page can take 10 seconds on some speed tests. I'm more than a little clueless when it comes to nginx, so any help with what to look into, or how to add server-side caching, would be so valuable. It might even be some problem with the disk in the server, but here's a portion of my nginx conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server { ... # various location based directing goes on here
```

Thanks for looking, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

nginx for Windows is apparently beta software.  I'd really suggest moving to something that's actually tested and known to work on Windows.  Apache would be my suggestion.

From the [nginx for windows docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html):

```
Only the select() request processing method is currently used, so high performance and scalability should not be expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything specifically *wrong* about your configuration, except maybe your keepalive_timeout could be probably better set to 5 or 10. Doing so isn't going to fix your problem tho. I do have some thoughts:

- you don't need any server side caching. Your site is already super simple
- where is this hosted? Maybe the pipe to your webserver is congested?
- You have some relatively large PNGs on the page. Converting these to JPG and lowering the quality slightly will get you a significant size difference (over 50%)
- do you RDP to the server? If you open the website locally, is it also slow? If so, then maybe disk is your problem, though in general I would doubt it, but it really depends on the infrastructure this is all being served from.